# Python standard function for dual of map

Tags: python, dictionary

Does the Python language have a built-in function for an analog of `map` that sends an argument to a sequence of functions, rather than a function to a sequence of arguments?

Plain `map` would have "type" (thinking like Haskell) `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`; is there anything with the corresponding type `a -> [(a -> b)] -> [b]`?

I could implement this in a number of ways. Here's using a `lambda`

```
def rev_map(x, seq):
    evaluate_yourself_at_x = lambda f: f(x)
    return map(evaluate_yourself_at_x, seq)


rev_map([1,2], [sum, len, type])
```

which prints `[3, 2, list]`.

I'm just curious if this concept of "induce a function to evaluate itself at me" has a built-in or commonly used form.

One motivation for me is thinking about dual spaces in functional analysis, where a space of elements which used to be conceived of as arguments passed to functions is suddenly conceived of as a space of elements which are functions whose operation is to induce another function to be evaluated at them.

You could think of a function like `sin` as being an infinite map from numbers to numbers, you give `sin` a number, `sin` gives you some associated number back, like `sin(3)` or something.

But then you could also think of the number 3 as an infinite map from functions to numbers, you give 3 a function `f` and 3 gives you some associated number, namely `f(3)`.

I'm finding cases where I'd like some efficient syntax to suddenly view "arguments" or "elements" as "function-call-inducers" but most things, e.g. my lambda approach above, seem clunky.

Another thought I had was to write wrapper classes for the "elements" where this occurs. Something like:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class MyFloat(float):
    def __call__(self, f):
        return f(self)

m = MyFloat(3)
n = MyFloat(2)

MyFloat(m + n)(type)
MyFloat(m + n)(print)
```

which will print `__main__.MyFloat` and `5.0`.

But this requires a lot of overhead to redefine data model operators and so on, and clearly it's not a good idea to push around your own version of very basic things like `float` which will be ubiquitous in most programs. It's also easy to get it wrong, like from my example above, doing this:

```
# Will result in a recursion error.
MyFloat(3)(MyFloat(4))
```

Comment: There is not, as far as I'm aware, anything in the standard library to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function for that. Simply because that's definitely not a commonly used concept. Plus Python is not designed to solve mathematical problems.

As for the implementation here's the shortest one you can get IMHO:

```
rev_map = lambda x, seq: [f(x) for f in seq]
```

Note that the list comprehension is so short and easy that wrapping it with a function seems to be unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: The last comment just seems like an opinion to me. If this was a common operation for you, you might want to encapsulate it in a function rather than repeating the syntax for the comprehension everywhere. Or you might not. It would depend and either could be good or bad in some contexts. I also think the last comment applies equally well to `map`, for which `map(f, seq)` could just be `[f(s) for s in seq]`. So to the extent that having `map` as a function is good (which yes, people debate) then so to would be `rev_map`.

Comment: Another reason to have it in a function would be encapsulating away the details of how it follows the iterator protocol to iterate, so for example if I wanted to handle how `rev_map` behaved on a sequence of generators different than a sequence of functions, or if I wanted to try to return the same sequence type (`tuple`, `list`, whatever) as what was passed to me.

Comment: @EMS **1)** The list comprehension is almost always used instead of `map`. The only reason to use `map` is when you want to pass it to another function. Again: extremely rare. **2)** Encapsulating that simple list comprehension barely makes the code shorter. You don't solve the "repetition" problem. **3)** Changing how `rev_map` works results in reviewing every place it is used in. You could just go through comprehensions directly. You gain nothing. Unless you change the implementation detail that does not affect neither arguments nor returned value. I can't imagine that here though.

Comment: @EMS **4)** Yeah, it is opinion. You can ignore everything except for the first sentence which answers your question. But then again you might learn something useful.

Comment: I'm not suggesting encapsulation solves code verbosity; it solves different problems. One problem I have is there seems to be a clear condescending tone to this answer. I see this a lot. The answer would be better just as the first sentence, which may indeed mean the question should just be closed. Regardless, the rest of the answer is not instructive and makes me feel like you're trying to place normative judgements on someone else's programming goals without knowing what they are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @EMS Condescending tone? Normative judgements? Dude, you are definitely overreacting. If my answer answers your question then please mark it as such. If you have a question or comment that actually is relevant to the question then please post it as well. Especially those misterious things you are trying to accomplish. If you say that it matters then you should've started with it.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr: As a rule, Python really likes list/generator comprehensions, much more than it likes functional programming.  `map()` and `filter()` are rarely combined with `lambda` in practice, and `functools.reduce()` isn't even a builtin.  None of this is normative, of course, but in casual conversation you may see it treated as such.